# Lisp Function that Returns a Sum

Tags: list, sum, lisp, iteration, clisp

I am trying to write a weird function, so bear with me here. This function should take a list `L` as a parameter and have a `sum` variable. If `L` is not a list, it should return `nil`. Otherwise, it should iterate through each element of the list and do the following:

- If the element is a number and less than zero, it should subtract 1 from the sum.
- If the element is a number and greater than zero, it should add 1 to the sum.
- if the element is 0 or not a number, then it should add 0 to the sum.

Here's the code I have, but it returns 0 regardless of arguments passed in:

```
(defun sigsum (L)
  (let ((sum 0))                   ;;variable sum
  (if (not (listp L))              ;;if L is not a list
      nil                          ;;return nil
      (dotimes (i (length L))      ;;otherwise loop through L
        (if (numberp (elt L i))    ;;if each element is a number
            (if (< (elt L i) 0)    ;;if is less than 0 subtract 1 from sum
                (- sum 1)
            (if (> (elt L i) 0)    ;;if greater than 0 add 1 to sum
                (+ sum 1))
            (+ sum 0))             ;;else add 0 to sum
          (+ sum 0)))              ;;not a number so add 0 to sum
  )
  sum)                             ;;return sum
)
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defun discrete (lis)
 (cond
  ((and (listp lis) (not (equal lis nil)))
   (let ((sum 0))
    (loop for item in lis do
     (cond ((or (not (numberp item)) (equal 0 item)) t)
      ((and (numberp item) (> item 1)) (setf sum (+ 1 sum)))
      ((and (numberp item) (< item 1)) (setf sum (- sum 1)))))
    sum))))
```

Usage:`(discrete '(-1 2 3 0 2 2 -1 2 34 0 -1))`=> 3

`(discrete '(-4 a b))`=> -1

`(discrete '())` => NIL

`(discrete '(a s d f))`=> 0

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have described the problems in your code, but it might be beneficial to look at other ways of solving the problem.  This is a pretty typical case for a *reduction* with a *key function* (see [**reduce**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm)).  You can sum up the elements in **list** with **(reduce '+ list)**.  However, you don't want to just sum up the elements, some of which might not be numbers, you want to map each element to a number (-1, 0, or 1), and add those up.  That means you need a key function.  First, let's define the function that takes an element to either -1, 0, or 1:

```
(defun to-number (x)
  (cond
    ((and (numberp x) (< x 0)) -1)
    ((and (numberp x) (> x 0)) 1)
    ((or (not (numberp x)) (zerop x)) 0)))
```

Then your **sum** function needs to return **nil** if its argument is not a list, or **(reduce '+ … :key 'to-number)** if its argument is a list:

```
(defun sum (thing)
  (if (not (listp thing))
      nil
      (reduce '+ thing :key 'to-number)))
```

Conceptually, this approach is the same as *applying* the addition operator to the result of **(mapcar 'to-number list)**, but **reduce** is generally preferred, because there can be a maximum number of arguments a function can be called with, so **(apply '+ (mapcar …))** breaks if **(mapcar …)** returns a list that's longer than that.  The other problem is that **mapcar** will allocate a whole new list to hold the intermediate values (the results of **to-number**), which is an unnecessary space usage.

Comment: Good solution. You could replace (if (not (listp thing)) ...) with (when (listp thing) (reduce ...), to be more concise.

Comment: @DanielKochmański It would be more concise, but a bit less explicit.  It comes down to preferred style, I think.  I tend to use **when** in doing side effecting things (e.g., `(when (minusp x) (setf x (- x)))`), but I like to make return values explicit.  I know that the value of `(when nil ...)` *is* explicitly defined to be `nil`, but seeing `(defun foo ... (when ...))` makes me thing that the return value of `foo` should be ignoreable, not that it should always be "the empty list or a number", where as `(if ... '() (reduce '+ ...))` is more clearly an empty list or a number.

Comment: Guess you are right about preferred style. Sorry for being picky.

Comment: @DanielKochmański Not all all;  I don't claim that my preferred style is *right* in any objective way;  it's just my personal preference.  I've been influenced a bit by pure functional programming, so I find some appeal in being able to say "the input to this function can be anything;  if it's not a list, then the empty list is returned; if the input is a list, then the result is...".  I just like the almost piece-wise definition of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(+ sum 1)` *returns* one more than `sum`.  It does not change `sum`.  You can get where you want using `incf` or `decf`, which modify places.

You could also use `loop`:

```
(loop :for element :in list
      :count (and (numberp element) (plusp element)) :into plus
      :count (and (numberp element) (minusp element)) :into minus
      :finally (return (- plus minus)))
```

`Signum` is also useful, but it has float contagion (if any of the numbers are floats, the result will be a float as well).

```
(loop :for element :in list
      :when (numberp element)
      :sum (signum element))
```

Answer (score 2):

`(- sum 1)` does not update any variables. Since you don't use the result it goes away. It's like this is all programming languages. `sum + 1` in an Algol language (like C) does not update `sum`.

If you want to update a variable you can use `setf`:

```
(setf sum (+ sum 1))
(setf sum (- sum 1))
```

Or you can use `incf` and `decf` that are macroes that expand to the same as the above expressions.

There are many other ways you can do it in CL. You can use reduce

```lisp
(defun mysignum (list)
  (if (listp list)
      (reduce (lambda (e acc)
                (+ acc
                   (cond ((or (not (numberp e)) (zerop e)) 0)
                         ((< e 0) -1)   
                         (t 1))))
              list)
       nil))
```

You can use loop:

```lisp
(defun mysignum (list)
  (if (listp list)
      (loop :for e :in list
        :when (and (numberp e) (< e 0))
           :summing -1
        :end
        :when (and (numberp e) (> e 0))
           :summing +1
        :end)
       nil))
```