# Difference between (loop for) and (loop :for) in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I just saw the answer of Sylwester to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427312/lisp-function-that-returns-a-sum), and I thought strange that the loop has colons everywhere.

Usually, I would write

```
(loop for n below 10 do (princ n) (terpri))
```

instead of

```
(loop :for n :below 10 :do (princ n) (terpri))
```

After some tests, I see that with the first loop, the symbols `for`, `below` and `do` are then part of cl-user (**edit** : actually not `do`, only the other two, probably because `do` is also a macro in the cl package), not with the second. Likewise, a 'X alone will then be part of cl-user, not ':X. The `symbol-package` function tells me the latter is in the keyword package.

Now, the first loop, without colons, looks much prettier to me, so I would like to know if the preceding remarks are a good reason to use the second one instead. That the symbols become "included" in the current package looks rather inoffensive, but maybe I have overlooked the consequences.

Any idea?

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, definitely a duplicate.

Comment: I guess I do it to distingush loop keywords from variables/expressions. `(loop :for element :below below-average :counting (> element above-average))` is easier to read correctly than `(loop for element below below-average counting (> element above-average))`

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, and with syntax coloring it looks much better. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You moslty already answered your own question, the difference is as you described. `:some-symbol` will be in `:KEYWORD` package, and `'SOME-SYMBOL` will be in your current package `CL-USER` by default. In `loop` macro it's just a matter of taste. Some people prefer to use `:for` notation to get better syntax highlighting in their text editor, for example.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of this choice before.

Comment: You can use symbols in other packages, too, not just the current or keyword packages.  This answer would be improved by a reference of *why* this is permissible, I think.  (It's not too hard to figure out what's going on, but without a reference, it's hard to know whether this is a bug or intended behavior.  (I know it's intended.))

Answer (score 3):

```
CL-USER 23 > (find-symbol "LOOP" "CL")
LOOP
:EXTERNAL

CL-USER 24 > (find-symbol "FOR" "CL")
NIL
NIL
```

`LOOP` is a symbol in the `COMMON-LISP` package and it is exported. `FOR` is neither. Thus in every package which does not have a `FOR` symbol and does not inherit one, one will add such a symbol when writing a `LOOP FOR` loop.

That's it. Usually that should be no problem...